# How to insert complex json file into mysql database using php?

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, arrays, json

I have a json file that contains multiple keys and values. Some values are strings and some array and object. How can I insert that json file into mysql database in json format using php.

```
[
{
    "wordNumber": 40,
    "word": "Vocabulary 40",
    "meaning": [
        {"form": "adjective","values": ["Lorem Ipsum is not simply random text.","It is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted by the readable content of a page when looking at its layout."]}
    ],
    "partsOfSpeech": ["adjective"],
    "otherForms": [
        {"form": "noun","words": ["Adequacy"]},
        {"form": "adverb","words": ["Adequately"]}
    ],
    "synonyms": [
        {"form": "Adjective","words": ["Acceptable","All right","Secent","Qualified","Satisfactory","Suitable","Tolerable","Sufficient","Competent"]}
    ],
    "antonyms": [
        {"form": "Adjective","words": ["Insufficient","Deficient","lacking","Inadequate","Unacceptable","Unsatisfactory","Unqualified","Unsuitable"]}
    ],
    "hintletters": ["a","u","q"],
    "categories": {
        "section": 4,
        "group": 2
    },
    "examples": [
        {"form": "adjective","values": ["Employees did not have adequate training.","This car is adequate for our family.","Total amount of workers are adequate for this project."]}
    ]
},{
    "wordNumber": 41,
    "word": "Vocabulary 41",
    "meaning": [
        {"form": "adjective","values": ["Lorem Ipsum is not simply random text.","It is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted by the readable content of a page when looking at its layout."]}
    ],
    "partsOfSpeech": ["adjective"],
    "otherForms": [
        {"form": "noun","words": ["Adequacy"]},
        {"form": "adverb","words": ["Adequately"]}
    ],
    "synonyms": [
        {"form": "Adjective","words": ["Acceptable","All right","Secent","Qualified","Satisfactory","Suitable","Tolerable","Sufficient","Competent"]}
    ],
    "antonyms": [
        {"form": "Adjective","words": ["Insufficient","Deficient","lacking","Inadequate","Unacceptable","Unsatisfactory","Unqualified","Unsuitable"]}
    ],
    "hintletters": ["a","u","q"],
    "categories": {
        "section": 5,
        "group": 1
    },
    "examples": [
        {"form": "adjective","values": ["Employees did not have adequate training.","This car is adequate for our family.","Total amount of workers are adequate for this project."]}
    ]
}
]
```

I have tried but when I insert data into the database all my arrays and objects become strings and they display as "Array" this word. I can not access those data later.

I have used this php code to insert data into the database -

```
<?php 

$connect = mysqli_connect("localhost","User","password","databaseName");

$fileName = "data2.json";

$data = file_get_contents($fileName);

$array = json_decode($data, true);

foreach($array as $row)
{
    $sql = "INSERT INTO vocabulary_data(wordNumber,word,meaning,partsOfSpeech,otherForms,synonyms,antonyms,hintletters,categories,examples) VALUES('".$row["wordNumber"]."','".$row["word"]."','".$row["meaning"]."','".$row["partsOfSpeech"]."','".$row["otherForms"]."','".$row["synonyms"]."','".$row["antonyms"]."','".$row["hintletters"]."','".$row["categories"]."','".$row["examples"]."')";

    mysqli_query($connect, $sql);
}

echo "All data inserted";

?>
```

I have used this PHP code to access my json data from the database -

```
<?php 

$connect = mysqli_connect("localhost","User","password","databaseName");

$result = mysqli_query($connect, "SELECT * from data_table");
$json_array = array();

while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
{
    $json_array[] = $row;
}

print(json_encode($json_array));

?>


But
```

when I access data it shows me this problem.

```
    [{"wordNumber":"40","word":"Vocabulary 
40","meaning":"Array","partsOfSpeech":"Array","otherForms":"Array",
"synonyms":"Array","antonyms":"Array","hintletters":"Array",
"categories":"Array","examples":"Array"},{"wordNumber":"41",
"word":"Vocabulary 41",
"meaning":"Array","partsOfSpeech":"Array","otherForms":"Array",
"synonyms":"Array","antonyms":"Array","hintletters":"Array",
"categories":"Array","examples":"Array"}]
```

Please, can anyone help to solve this problem?

Comment: Looking at your JSON, `meaning` will be an array once decoded. What do you want to store for it? the JSON value?

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to pass the array into DB field.
if you want to store json into db then you need to pass by json_encode($array_name) which will again convert your array to json and stre into db as string.

```
       $sql = "INSERT INTO vocabulary_data(wordNumber,word,meaning,partsOfSpeech,otherForms,synonyms,antonyms,hintletters,categories,examples) VALUES('".$row["wordNumber"]."','".$row["word"]."','".json_encode($row["meaning"])."','".json_encode($row["partsOfSpeech"])."','".json_encode($row["otherForms"])."','".json_encode($row["synonyms"])."','".json_encode($row["antonyms"])."','".json_encode($row["hintletters"])."','".json_encode($row["categories"])."','".json_encode($row["examples"])."')";
```

After storing json into db you will get it into json format and if you need to use it then you need to fetch it from DB and use it.

After storing json in DB you may not be possible to apply filters to db.

Comment: Thank you so for your help. It worked
I need one more favor. How can I fetch the data from the database?
I have used this code but not working - 
<?php 

$connect = mysqli_connect("localhost","user","password","databasname");

$result = mysqli_query($connect, "SELECT * from vocabulary_data");
$json_array = array();

while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
{
    $json_array[] = $row;
}

print(json_encode($json_array));

?>
Please, can you provide me the correct code?